# Parse command line args to process a list of files in bash?

Tags: string, bash, list, parsing

I want to create a script with some optional inputs parsed similar to how [this respone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14203146/3585557) explains but also containing a list of files with a certain extension.  Example usage would be

```
./myscript.sh -s 25 -q 0.2 *.txt
```

and the script would then store 25 into the `s` variable, 0.2 into the `q` varable, and the list of all the txt files would then get individually processed.  This is what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash -f

# set the default values
QMAX=0.2
PROFILESIZE=50

while [[ $# > 0 ]]
do
key="$1"
case $key in
    -q|--max_q)
    QMAX="$2"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
    -s|--profile_size)
    PROFILESIZE="$2"
    shift # past argument
    ;;
esac
shift # past argument or value
done

for var in "$@"
do
    if [[ $var == *".txt" ]]
    then
        # do something on for real on each file here
        echo $QMAX $PROFILESIZE $var
    fi
done
```

As is, I can run with the default values by commenting out the `while` loop.  Without commenting it out, it reads through the inputs and there are none left for the `for` loop to compare.  I think the best option is to create a list of the files in the `while` loop, then use that in the `for` loop.  Any ideas of how I would do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just append a `*)` case that stores the argument to an array.

```
*) files+=("$1") ;;
```

And then iterate over files instead of `$@`:

```
for file in "${files[@]}" ; do
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do.  It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getopts` command to handle the optional arguments, leaving the remaining arguments in `$@`.

```
while getopts 's:q:' opt; do
    case $opt in
        s) PROFILESIZE=$OPTARG ;;
        q) QMAX=$OPTARG ;;
    esac
done
shift $(( OPTIND - 1 ))
```

This does have the drawback of not supporting long options, however.

Answer (score 0):

The first sugestion is do not implement it from scratch and use "getopts/getopt" instead. However, if for some reason you can, and assuming options are always before arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash 

# set the default values
QMAX=0.2
PROFILESIZE=50

while [[ $# > 0 ]]
do
 key="$1"
 case $key in
 -q|--max_q)
   QMAX="$2"
   shift 2 # past argument
  ;;
  -s|--profile_size)
    PROFILESIZE="$2"
    shift 2 # past argument
   ;;
  *)
   break
   ;;

# --) 
# break
# ;;

  esac
done

for var in "$@"
do
  if [[ $var == *".txt" ]]
  then
    # do something on for real on each file here
    echo $QMAX $PROFILESIZE $var
  fi
done
```

Comment: Do I HAVE to have the options always before the arguments?  Without the `break` statement, couldn't the input be in any order?

Comment: If arguments and options are mixed, then you need an auxiliar array as suggested by @choroba. However, it is not very usual, and even not good to allow them mixed. In fact, it is usual allow an optional  "---" with the meaning of "end of options, start of arguments". In this way, an argument can have the same name than an option.